# LINQ Sorting List<T> based on string Name property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, linq

I have the following:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string query = context.Request.QueryString["term"];
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer JsonSerializer =
        new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<Category> Categs = Category.getAll();
    var result = from c in Categs where Categs.Contains(c.Name) select c;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));
}
```

Trying to return a list of [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ] for jQuery UI autocomplete. I have Categories which have ID and Name properties and I want to filter the List based on the "term" in the querystring and Name property. How should i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, .NET naming conventions say that `JsonSerializer` should be `jsonSerializer`, `Categs` should be `categs`, and `getAll()` should be `GetAll()`. Also you could avoid typing out `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` twice by replacing the first occurance with `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string upperTerm = term.ToUpper();

var result = Category.getAll()
  .Where(c => c.Name.ToUpper().Contains(upperTerm))
  .Select(c => new { label = c.Name, value = c.Id });
```

Then JSON serialize `result`.

Answer (score 2):

If your end goal is making that list of `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]` and have it sorted by name, then this should work:

```
result
  .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
  .Select(x => new { label: x.Name, value: x.Id }); // create an anonymous type
```

Edit: Your current query:

```
var result = from c in Categs where Categs.Contains(c.Name) select c;
```

*Looks* wrong. I think that query is the same as just selecting all `Categs`. If you want to query based on the term they sent, replace `c.Name` with `query` in that linq expression:

```
var result = from c in Categs where Categs.Contains(query) select c;
```